# Getting the values of the two closest parameters out of three

Tags: excel, fetch

I have an excel spreadsheet with data in three columns:

```
0.89  1.2   0.96
12.3  14.7  20.2
```

I need a function that recognizes the two closest items of the three,
so that i can average between them to.

the result should be:

```
0.925
13.5
```

something like `=AVERAGE(__yourFunction__(A1:A3,2))`

i hope there is a better way than eliminating the `MAX(ABS(A1-A2),ABS(A1-A3),ABS(A3-A2))`

Comment: is there always only three column?

Comment: Yes. well, at least in this sort of biological test. the writing for yourFunction is just to allow more complex functions for which my question is a specific case

Comment: so, if you would have, say, 7 columns of data, you still need to calculate average of two closest values?

Comment: that case i might need the average of 4, or 5 of them

Answer (score 0):

First enter the following UDF in a standard module:

```
Public Function AVr(r1 As Range, r2 As Range, r3 As Range) As Variant
    v1 = r1.Value
    v2 = r2.Value
    v3 = r3.Value
    d12 = Abs(v1 - v2)
    d13 = Abs(v1 - v3)
    d23 = Abs(v2 - v3)
    mn = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(d12, d13, d23)
    If mn = d12 Then
        AVr = (v1 + v2) / 2
        Exit Function
    End If
    If mn = d13 Then
        AVr = (v1 + v3) / 2
        Exit Function
    End If
    AVr = (v2 + v3) / 2
End Function
```

Then place values in **A1**, **B1**, and **C1**.

Finally in **D1** enter:

=AVr(A1,B1,C1)

**EDIT:**

This, of course, begs the question:

if the values are 1., 2., and 3......do you expect 1.5 or 2.5 as the answer???

Comment: Thanks!
what i did is eventually this just without a function. i really hoped there is an excel ready-made function... if its 1,2 & 3 then ideally the function returns 2, but that requires a bit more mess...